# Meaning of parts of a transaction created by an online wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info

I would like to know this complete transaction details.

1. The highlighted wallet is ID with 0.000496 BTC's is my wallet
2. Wallet with 2.7+BTC is I dont know what it is and why it is linked to my wallet ID?
3. Wallets on the left indicates red globe and green globe. What does that signify?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/19278/5406

Answer (score 1):

I interpret this as follows: you bought some bitcoin on Binance and requested a withdrawal. Binance processed the withdrawal in a transaction that batched 24 payments—they paid you and 23 others. They also sent some 0.60413290 BTC back to themselves. (Unfortunately, the latter is  obvious because Binance always uses the same address.) The 2.7+ BTC refer to the transaction output Binance spent in the input to this transaction.

The red and green globes signify whether the transaction outputs newly created by this transaction have been spent since. Green indicates [unspent outputs](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4301/5406), and red indicates spent. I deduce that your output has not been spent yet.

Also, FYI, you left enough letters visible for the transaction id and address to be identifiable.

Comment: It should be noted that completely redacting the transaction ID and address wouldn't help. Just the input or output list would be enough to uniquely identify the transaction, and other characteristics – transaction size, weight and fee – can be combined to narrow the possibilities to just four transactions.

Comment: Thanks for educating me. Is there a way I can connect with you one on one?

Comment: Yeah, if you were concerned about privacy you should have used a foreign transaction for your example.

Comment: @Nikko: I'm not sure whether you meant me or Vojtěch, but while I help with public content on this site, I'm not looking to provide private tutoring or assistance on basic use of Bitcoin.